# order vector by number of occurences in R

Tags: r

I have A vector:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,3,2,2)
```

Now I want to order this vector on number of occurences, I know I can count the number of occurences with table:

```
x.order <- table(x)[rev(order(table(x)))]
```

Gives me:

> 2  3  1
>   3  2  1

Now I know, I first have to select the values of x, which are 2, then the values of x which are 3 and then the values where x is 1. How can I perform this last step?
The final output has to look like:

> 2,2,2,3,3,1

Or is there a better way to order the vector by number of occurences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x<-c(1,2,3,3,2,2)
x.order <- sort(table(x), TRUE)
rep(as.numeric(names(x.order)), times=x.order)
#[1] 2 2 2 3 3 1
```